# Microphone needs permission from google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microphone

Google chrome will not allow me to use my microphone on singsnap. I want to know how to turn on the permission for my microphone.

Comment: Does it work with some other browser by chance

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Singsnap is a flash application?

Answer (score 1):

At  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en Google says:

> Allow sites to access your camera and microphone ...
>
> Advanced settings
>
> You can choose a different default permissions setting and manage exceptions in Content settings.
>
> 1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Click Show advanced settings.
> 4. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings. In the "Media" section:
>
>    - Ask me when a site requires access to my camera and microphone:    Select this option if you want Chrome to alert you whenever a site requests access to your camera and microphone.
>    - Do not allow sites to    access my camera and microphone: Select this option to automatically deny any site requests to access your camera and microphone

Answer (score 1):

1. When in Gmail, click the padlock icon in your URL bar. That will bring down a list of your permissions.
2. Look for the camera icon with a red `x` across it.
3. Click the camera icon and choose "Always allow on this site" or "Use global default (Ask)".
4. Reload the page for the changes to take effect. Now you should be able to access your microphone.